# Why there is an existing default cookie name in Cookie in GWT?

Tags: gwt, cookies, gwtp

I just found out that there is an existing default cookie name in Cookie before i actually adds my cookie name into it. That default cookie is JSESSIONID.

```
Collection<String> cookies = Cookies.getCookieNames();
for (String cookie : cookies) {
    String cookieValue = Cookies.getCookie(cookie);
    String[] itemMeaningIDcompanyMeaningID=cookie.split("_");
}
```

If i live the default cookie there, then i have a problem cos I need to convert cookie name into array so i may split the default cookie & that could cause runtime error.

i suspect that the default cookie is used for something else in GWT, so if i remove it then the system may not run properly.

So my question is, should i remove that default cookie or i just leave it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSESSIONID is a cookie generated by the servlet container (like Tomcat or Jetty) and used for session management. You should leave it there unless you don't use sessions and don't plan to use them ever (which is rarely the case for any non trivial webapp).

Comment: is there any space or underscore in JSESSIONID name?

Comment: No, the name is really "JSESSIONID".